# How to update a value in Sql with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone help finding the right formula for Update

```
protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString1 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kickstarterConn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection com = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
        com.Open();
        string sql1 = "UPDATE Project SET Foundet = @Foundet ";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, com);

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foundet", TextBox7.Text);
        com.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You've almost done. Just add `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery` before `com.Close()`.

Comment: ...and use `using(var com = new SqlConnection(connectionString1) { }`

Comment: Still it doesn't change the variable in sql. It remains the same

Comment: Your SQL command changes the column "Foundet" in the table "Project" **for all rows** of that table. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also: [Don't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @HansKesting sorry for replying so late. What should i use?

Comment: For that "AddWithValue"? Please read the article, it provides reasons and solutions. For the "all rows"? Usually there is a "`WHERE`" part in an `UPDATE` command, to limit the effect to specific rows (or just one)

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the command.

```
com.Open();
string sql1 = "UPDATE Project SET Foundet = @Foundet ";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, com);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foundet", TextBox7.Text);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.Close();
```